# mongoose library expects json but cannot make a dynamic one from nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongoose

This is more related to javascript / json than on mongoose library.

Mongoose expects OR conditions in json format like this,

> ```
>  { $or : [ { "doc_no" : /first/i  }, { "doc_type" : /second/i  } ] }
> ```

but when I try to build this dynamically,
I achieved only this

> ```
> { '$or': [ [ [Object], [Object] ] ] }
> ```

from the code

```
var and_cond = []
or_cond.push ({ "doc_no" : /first/i  })
or_cond.push ({ "doc_type" : /second/i  })
```

I tried to use JSON.stringify, but isn't usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
const orConditions = { $or: [] };

orConditions.$or.push({ "doc_no": /first/i  });
orConditions.$or.push({ "doc_no": /first/i  });
```

This will create the following object:

```
{ 
  $or: [
    { "doc_no" : /first/i  },
    { "doc_no" : /secon/i  }
  ] 
}
```

Comment: awesome! I couldn't find it anywhere.